# Jquery get value of cookie and send to GA

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to get the value of a cookie from my browser and send that to GA, I can do page views and events etc, But I am confused how to handle cookies?

```
  var gaData = {
    exp: "EXP",
    guest: 'page viewed with guest',

  };

  // load out
  ga('send', 'event', gaData.exp, "pageview", gaData.guest);
```

This is basic code I know but how would I define the cookie and get the value? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can send your (cookie) value to Google Analytics with a **custom dimension**: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets